# tab navigation and scroll

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, sapui5, setfocus

I have table which has many column, so there is a horizontal scroll bar.

let's say I have 10 column, 7 are visible, 3 are not. the problem I have now is:

1. if the cell is invisible and it has value, when I use tab navigate to that cell and set focus to that input, the horizontal scrollbar didn't scroll to the column.
   if that cell is empty, it will scroll and make that column visible.
2. the cell which has value, it will select all the value(highlighted) when get focused, is there a way to manipulate the behavior?

Comment: It's hard to visualize what you're describing. Can you create a [mcve] for us?

Comment: forget to mention, I don't have the scroll problem in IE.  it didn't scroll in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question 2:

For each template of `oTable2` you can attach a jQuery event handler and do whatever you want inside:

```
oTemplate.addEventDelegate({
    onAfterRendering: function (oEvent) {
        var oClonedTextField = oEvent.srcControl;
        oClonedTextField.$().find("input").focus(function () {
            this.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        });
    }
});
```